# Property [hora_inicio] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo una consulta donde almacena en un array y solo funciona con `first()`, si coloco `get()` me marcar el error *Property [hora_inicio] does not exist on this collection instance*

La consulta `$paro` tiene los datos del campo "hora_inicio", anteriormente era necesario `first()`, pero ahora ya no se requiere.

Entiendo que `get()` recupera una colección.

```
 $jornadas = $jornada->get();
            foreach ($jornadas as $jornada) {
                $detalleCategoria = array();

                   foreach ($categoriasParos as $key => $categoria) {
                    $detalleCausa = array();
                    foreach ($categoria->causasParos as $key2 => $causaParo) {
                        if ($jornada) {
                           
                            $paro = Paro::where('jornada_id', $jornada->id)
                              ->where('causa_paro_id', $causaParo->id)
                              ->get();

                            array_push(
                                $detalleCausa,
                                array(
                                    'causa' => $causaParo,
                                    'paro' => $paro ? $paro : ''
                                )
                            );
                        } else {
                            array_push(
                                $detalleCausa,
                                null
                            );
                        }
                    }
                    array_push(
                        $detalleCategoria,
                        array(
                            'categoria' => $categoria,
                            'causas' => $detalleCausa
                        )
                    );

                }
```

En otra parte del código lo mando a llamar

```
 if (!empty($causa['paro'])) {
                    $horaInicio = strtotime($causa['paro']->hora_inicio);
                    $horaFin = strtotime($causa['paro']->hora_fin);
```

¿Es posible convertir esa colección a un arreglo? ¿Usar la colección?

Comment: Bienvenid@ a stackoverflow en español. Si pongo en el buscador me aparecen [43 resultados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Property+*+does+not+exist+on+this+collection+instance)... ¿Ninguna de las preguntas/respuestas ya publicadas te sirve? Te sugiero leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y evitar duplicados. También, aprovechar y [hacer el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla.

Comment: de poder si se puede, pero el codigo que has brindado no describe al 100% lo que pretendes hacer ... y sobre todo si estas en un punto donde te sale un error, no queda claro... o si esperas que te hagamos el codigo que se encargue de hacer lo que describes no es correcto...

Comment: creo que debes aclarar y desarrollar un poco mas lo que intentesas hacer.

Comment: El error viene dado porque con first estas llamando un solo registros y puedes acceder a el como “$causa['paro']->hora_inicio” pero cuando utilizas get() está obteniendo varios registros por ende no puedes acceder a estos de la manera que lo estás intentando.

Comment: por ende debes recorrer todos lo datos mediante un for y agregarle su respectivo índice $causa['paro'][n]->hora_inicio